# Why do i get a null DataSource when running this code using HikariCP?

Tags: spring-boot, datasource, hikaricp

I'm running this code to set my config and get a DataSource to access a database but when i call ds.getDataSource() i get a null value. What am i missing there?

```
    private static HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    private static HikariDataSource ds;

    static {
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:5656/...");
        config.setUsername("");
        config.setPassword("");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
        config.setConnectionTimeout(30000);
        config.setIdleTimeout(600000);
        config.setMaxLifetime(1800000);
        ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    public static DataSource getDataSource() {
        return ds.getDataSource();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you even doing this? You are using Spring boot which configures the `DataSource` for you. Also the `HikariDataSource` IS the `DataSource`. No need to call `getDataSource`.

Comment: Im using `try (DSLContext create = DSL.using(dataSource, SQLDialect.MYSQL))` to connect to my DB, how do i get my DataSource object from if that is not the way?

Comment: For reference, i followed this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/hikaricp

Comment: Inject the datasource and use it from there. As your tags indicate you are using Spring Boot then use it properly, also it you want to use JOOQ then use the proper Spring Boot starter for JOOQ and benefit from autoconfiguration. In short you are using the wrong tutorial combined with Spring Boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so i wasn't familiar with this aspect of SpringBoot, for anyone having the same problem here is what i did to make the `@Autowired` work:

I need to use the `DataSource` in my a `QuickSearchService` class which i defined as a `@Service`. In that service i can call the HikariCP DataSource with `@Autowired`:

```
@Service
public class QuickSearchService{

@Autowired
private DataSource ds;

...
    
}
```

Then when i needed to use the service i `@Autowired` it aswell on call:

```
public class UsingService {

@Autowired
private QuickSearchService qss;

...

}
```

Finaly i had to use `@ComponentScan` on the application main class to tell the server to find the components that need to be autowired:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"example.services", ...})
public class DemoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args){
...
}

}
```

Then i can configure the DataSource in the application.properties.